# Want to refer to a particular container in a list view which is made scrollable horizontally

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a column which has two widgets wherein there's a list view of 3 different containers which is scrollable horizontally and there an inkwell.
What Inkwell is doing is that it is having a click functionality wherein if I click on that inkwell it should redirect me to one of the containers in the list view and also it should be able to scroll in the horizontal axis.

**But what I have coded down is it is navigating me to the desired screen but the thing is that the app bar is getting vanished and the scrolling ability is also not there and also few yellow line errors were also coming.**

Code Snippet:

```
import 'package:book/shared/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListExampleState createState() => _ListExampleState();
}

class _ListExampleState extends State<ListExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 800,
                  width: 1200,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Screen 1'), // 1st Page.
                  ),
                ),
                Screen2(), // 2nd Page
                Container(
                  height: 800,
                  width: 1200,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Screen 3'), // 3rd Page.
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 800,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    color: AppColors.getLightBlue(),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Screen2(),  /// Using the navigator is not solving the problem
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                      'Screen 2'), // The name should change as we navigate throgh differnt screen
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen2({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 800,
      width: 1200,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Screen 2'), // 2nd Page.
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me solve the error.

Tried the few packages such as scrollable_position_list, etc but nothing helped me with this.